Quart @stream_with_context decorator not persisting g global object
I presume that the quart @stream_with_context decorator would allow the g object to be make availble to the async generator. However it does not seem to be working.
Here is the simple quart app that I am trying
import asyncio
from datetime import datetime

from quart import Blueprint, stream_with_context, g
from quart import Quart
from quart.views import MethodView

blueprint = Blueprint('main', __name__)


class StreamTestResource(MethodView):
    async def get(self):
        g.username = 'test'

        @stream_with_context
        async def async_generator():
            print(g.username) # <----- This line throws error
            for i in range(5):
                await asyncio.sleep(1)
                time = datetime.isoformat(datetime.now())
                yield f'data: {time}\n\n'

        return async_generator(), 200, {
            'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked',
        }


blueprint.add_url_rule('/ping', view_func=StreamTestResource.as_view('ping'))

app = Quart(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(blueprint)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()


Error
 raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: username

